# Инверсия списков на Prolog

Tags: списки, prolog

Здравствуйте! Дано вот такое задание : "Дан список L1, элементом которого являются списки целых чисел. Построить список L2, изменив порядок элементов в L1 на обратный и изменить порядок на обратный в каждом подсписке." Сразу скажу, что встроенные предикаты и функции использовать нельзя (знаю что есть reverse).

Получился вот такой код (позаимствовал с одного форума):

```
inverse(List, Rev):- 
inv(List, [], Rev). 

inv([ ], Rev, Rev):- !. 
inv([H|T], SpList, Rev):- 
inv(T, [H|SpList], Rev).
```

Но при вводе

```
inverse([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],X).
```

Выдается

```
X = [[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]].
```

Как инвертировать и вложенные списки тоже, подскажите пожалуйста! Уже час пытаюсь, но пока одни ошибки валятся(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% Вариант с параметром-аккумулятором (reverse_nested/3) 
% Предикат верхнего уровня 
reverse_nested( X, Xr ):-
    reverse_nested( X, Xr, [] ).

%
reverse_nested( [], Z, Z ).

reverse_nested( [ H | T ], Z , Acc ) :- 
    atomic( H ),
    reverse_nested( T, Z, [ H | Acc ] ).

reverse_nested( [ X | T ], Z, Acc ) :-
    \+ atomic( X ),
    reverse_nested( X, Xr ),
    reverse_nested( T, Z, [ Xr | Acc] ). 

% Тест. 
goal :- reverse_nested( [ 1, [], [[ 2 ], 3 ],[ 4 ]], Xr ), write( Xr ).  

% результат [ [ 4 ], [ 3, [ 2 ]], [], 1 ]

:- initialization( goal ).
```